# Multiply and Divide functions do not have correct output in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, mathematics, formula

I am trying to calculate standard deviation `(observed - mean)/(mean)*100` but I noticed the part where you ".divide(longTermMean)", the math results results are incorrect. I tested out different formulas and found that the variables "longTermMean" and "monthlyObserved" subtract and add normally, and divide by integers normally, but when dividing or multiplying themselves, the math is incorrect. I am new to coding and geospatial data analysis.

To test out your math, for example, Month 3 (March) should have a % Deviation of 46%, not 36%.

Here is the full script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/4709b950a00b750e6108598721fdc3a0

```
// Calculate deviation in %
var deviation = months.map(function(month) {
  var longTermMean = monthlyRainfall
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month)).first()
  var monthlyObserved = observedRainfall
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month)).first()
  var deviation = ((monthlyObserved).subtract(longTermMean))
   .divide(longTermMean).multiply(100)
    .set('month', month)
  return deviation
})
```

Comment: How do you calculate the value of 46%? I calculated the deviation by using your approach and an expression and both results are identical.

Comment: So for March, the 'ObservedRainfall' was 65.648, the 'longTermMean' was 44.371. So then (65.648 - 44.371)/44.371 * 100 = 47.95%. In GEE, subtraction and addition of those variables work fine, dividing/multplying by integers works fine too, but it is only when dividing or multiply by each other that it gives the wrong output.

Comment: That explanation doesn't answer my question. How do you get the values of the 'ObservedRainfall'  equals to 65.648 and the 'longTermMean' equals to 44.371?

Comment: In the code you can edit the "var deviation" to view just the 'ObservedRainfall' by doing 'var deviation = (monthlyObserved)', and then run the script and it will generate the monthly observed rainfalls (March will have 65.648). And then you can edit the code again to 'var deviation = (longTermMean)' and run it and it will generate the longTermMean (March will be 44.371). This values are correct, I ran other scripts to double check. The error is in any sort of math that involves multiplying or dividing the 'monthlyObserved' and 'longTermMean' by each other.

Comment: Your last comment clarifies your problem. There is nothing wrong with multiply and divide functions in Google Earth Engine. I found out the issue. Definitively, your approach defining the deviation is wrong. Soon, I will prepare an answer.

Comment: Ok, I am looking forward to you answer, thank you!

Comment: Sir, you have my answer. If you think that it solves your problem please, mark it as accepted.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! How do I mark your answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adequate way for determining deviation values is as follows.

```
var monthlyRainfall_list = monthlyRainfall.toList(monthlyRainfall.size());

var allValues = monthlyRainfall_list.map(function (ele){
  
  var idx = monthlyRainfall_list.indexOf(ele);
  
  var longTermMean = ee.Image(ele)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), basin, 10000)
    .get('precipitation');

  var monthlyObserved = ee.Image(ee.List(monthlyTotals).get(idx))
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), basin, 10000)
    .get('precipitation');
  
  var deviation = ee.Number.expression('((monthlyObserved-longTermMean)/longTermMean)*100', {
    'monthlyObserved': monthlyObserved,
    'longTermMean': longTermMean
  });
  
  return deviation;
  
});
```

I used 'reduceRegion' method with **ee.List** objects because it is easier to export them to Google Drive as CSV. On the other hand, there is not any complication to use them for generating its respective chart. In this case, I used **ui.Chart.array.values** method instead **ui.Chart.image.series**.

After running the complete code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a75670d5e9163bfc9dac1bad91fb3722), I got result of following picture.

[image]

The first printed chart is by using your approach. The second one is by using the result produced with above function. It can be observed that the result for march month is as expected (47.954 %)